# session_start and $_SERVER variable in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a client which has wish that url referer gets send along contact email. This already worked and suddenly stopped over night, with no clues what's the problem.

The platform is, sadly, Wordpress.

This in the header.php:

```
if(!session_id()){
 //session_destroy();
 session_start();
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['referer'])){
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])&&!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  $ref=strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  if(strpos($ref,'facebook')!==false){$_SESSION['referer']="Facebook";$_SESSION['refererURL']=$ref;}
  elseif(strpos($ref,'google')!==false){$_SESSION['referer']="Google";$_SESSION['refererURL']=$ref;}
  else{$_SESSION['referer']="Web";$_SESSION['refererURL']=$ref;}
 }
}
```

and this is in my contact-us.php:

```
$referer=trim($_SESSION['referer']);
$refererURL=trim($_SESSION['refererURL']);
```

According to the code, I should be getting three different referers depending on where user has come from, but I'm constantly getting "Web" aka. no referer specified.

What am I doing wrong?

And to clarify:

- `session_start()` hasn't been run before header.php,
- `add_action( 'init', 'session_start' );` doesn't work,
- no errors produced, it just saves the wrong referer,
- this exact code has worked 1 day ago, now it doesn't and as far as I know, no changes has been made!

**EDIT:**
I have moved everything to `$_COOKIE` variables and removed entry from xmlrpc.php `$_COOKIE = array();` and it's working. It appears that wordpress has some strange logic when it comes to `$_SESSION`.

Comment: do this: `echo $refererURL` to verify the referrer is indeed not `web`

Answer (score 1):

Check the server configuration.It might happen that your php version at server might have been updated without intimation which caused in turning off the global variables.

you can check that by simply uploading an php file with following code in it

```
    <?php
     phpinfo();
     ?>
```

EDIT:
please refer to following links
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals

Comment: If I understand correctly, using global variables means that I can access `$_SESSION` variables by `$`, example: `$_SESSION['referer']` will be accessible by `$referer`. Since I'm not accessing `$_SESSION ` variables this way, I think that this is irrelevant. Or am I wrong? And I just checked, global variables are turned off.

Comment: sorry for my mistake
it aint global variable it is
"register_globals" make sure it is turned on

Comment: Off. Otherwise there would be quite some of unpredicted results and unexpected errors.

Comment: try turning it on using .htaccess and post the result here

Comment: Sorry, site is live and now it does what my client wanted - see my edited original question. And it's wordpress, it has some strange logic when it comes to using `$_SESSION`. Google is full of this events.

Comment: Something new to learn.But good to hear that at least it started working.
:)